# Python Discord.py Send message in channel from cog

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to adapt the code from the docs. I want to send a message to a specific channel every 5 seconds but I cannot access the channel it always returns None.

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.index = 0
        self.task.start()
        self.bot = bot

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def task(self):
        await self.bot.get_guild("").get_channel("").send("Test")
        print(self.index)

        self.index += 1

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

Answer (score -1):

It's always returning `None` because you're doing this:

```
await self.bot.get_guild("").get_channel("")
```

You need to pass in the actual `Guild` id & `Channel` id.

```
await self.bot.get_guild(guild_id_goes_here).get_channel(channel_id_goes_here)
```

Also make sure the id's are `ints`, not `strings`, and that your bot can see the relevant guild & channel.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_channel'

Comment: That means your bot can't see a guild with that ID. Are you sure you copied the correct ID?